# Adding controllers dynamically to a module in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In one of my partial views I want to include another script that will create controllers which will be used in this partial view. Is it possible?

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQPb9TNGeGwDZQZvPBam

Comment: Please specify what you want to achieve, as it is quite far from obvious.

Comment: Sounds like you want to lazy load a controller. See http://www.slideshare.net/nirkaufman/angularjs-lazy-loading-techniques and Google angularjs lazy load.